# Why is it bad to use myetherwallet.com for key generation on mobile?

Tags: myetherwallet

From my android, I read the myetherwallet.com mobile site that it is unsafe to generate keys in that manner. Why is it unsafe to generate keys on a mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some viruses on android can see what has been copied on the clipboard, that's why it's not adviceable I think.